# back stack and back press using fragment and activity android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I used 3 fragments in one activity using framelayout from 3rd fragment,it should go to one activity then on back press of that activity,it should redirect to that 3rd fragment and from on back press from 3rd fragment it should redirect to 1st fragment without blank screen? .i got blank screen and looping

Comment: Do you use `fragmentManager.addToBackstack()` when adding new fragment to the screen?

Comment: Please post the xml  and activity code

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed() and process the replace inside.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  //Check current fragment 
  Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
  if(f instanceof FragmentThird) {

  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

  // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
  // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentFirst);
  transaction.addToBackStack(null);

  // Commit the transaction
  transaction.commit();
  }
  return;
```

}